# Count the number of character that occur at same index after reversing the string

Tags: python, string, substring, logic

```
def count(dataStream):
    c=0
    for i,j in zip(dataStream, dataStream[::-1]):
        if(i==j):
            c+=1
    return c
```

I am able to pass 15/16 test case can someone please help me that where I am left which edge case I am missing

Count the number of character that occur at same index after reversing the string

Comment: Do you know what value assigned to *dataStream* is giving the wrong result

Comment: My 15 test case are getting pass

Comment: sample input
alphxxdida

output
4

Comment: Can you provide the problem statement?

Comment: @HappyPrajapat You haven't told us what the value of *dataStream* when the test case fails